# What is ms-cv in response header

Tags: header, response, http-response-codes

I am looking for the definition of ms-cv response header unfortunately i cannot find a good one

In one of my http response I saw this MS-CV: wrtqvas27jtgu2oq.0 and

Answer (score 2):

MS-CV stands for Microsoft Correlation Vector.  It is described here - https://github.com/microsoft/CorrelationVector

It looks like its mostly used for [distributed tracing](https://opentracing.io/docs/overview/what-is-tracing/).